# Wordpress / woocommerce - Output “parent“ product of an image in the media library

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am building a visual search, where a user can upload a photo. This photo gets checked against all images in my media library. If I get a hit, than the corresponding product should be outputted.

Is there a way to identify the product to which an image is assigned. Either as product image our gallery image.

(Update: I forgot to mention it's for woocommerce. So I need the product it's attached to)

Answer (score 2):

I dont think there is a way to get the post id of an image without looping through every product checking if the image id is attached to the post.

Comment: I'm sorry i forgot to mention it's for woocommerce. So I need the product it's attached to

Comment: Because when I edit a product and open the media library, I can filter the images to “only uploaded to this product“, then only the attached files are shown. Therefore I thought that there is a way to output the parent product somehow.

Comment: Well you can do that because you have the post_id.. its a one way logic.. the post knows about his attachments, but the attachments have no reference to the post ids

Comment: About 500 Products now, maybe up to 2000-3000 in future

Comment: Different approach (just thinking) are you doing any kind of image recognition with keywords? When your visual search get a hit you search in the background for the keyword linked to the image result.

Comment: No, actually it's a real visual search by optical attributes and my “products“ are people ;)

Comment: I think I have to go through all the products and save the attachments that are linked to some allocation table

Comment: Ah.. yeh that's a possible way.. maybe you can hook up to an action when uploading the image on a post. And sace that information in the meta table

Comment: This value in the media library „uploaded to“ is actually exactly what I need, if this would somehow accessible with the REST API?